# AngularJS how to dynamically split list in multiple columns

Tags: angularjs

I have a number of li items which I want evenly distributed across 3 different columns. So I need the 1st third of the list items to be shown in the first ul, the next third in the 2nd ul etc.

Right know my approach is somewhat static:

```
<ul class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
  <li ng-repeat="skill in skills.development | slice:0:10">
    {{ skill.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
  <li ng-repeat="skill in skills.development | slice:10:21">
    {{ skill.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
  <li ng-repeat="skill in skills.development | slice:21:32">
    {{ skill.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I create the 3 rows in my template and then I created a custom filter that slices the list so I can obtain the first 11 elements, the next 11 elements and so forth. Problem is that the number of rows in each ul is not assigned dynamically like so:

```
Math.ceil(skills.development.length / 3)
```

So if I have more elements I will have to manually change the number of rows. Filtering is an issue as well. Imagine that I search for a word with 5 matches in first column and one in the 2nd column. Then I would have completely uneven column sizes. The length should be recalculated dynamically when I filter the list.

Ideally not only the number of rows in a column is calculated dynamically, but also the number of columns. So if there are more than say 15 elements it should render three columns, but if there is only 10 elements 2 columns will look better (as there is only 5 elements in each). And if there are less than 5 elements only one column will be rendered.

I figured that I should either try to solve it in the view or make some sort of helper function similar to the custom filter function I already wrote. But how might I do that?

Comment: Questions about improving the code belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @UmurKontacı, this is an appropriate question for stackoverflow, just the title was not good. The OP fixed the title.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did not know about code review, but since I am not just asking how to refactor my code but how to add features by making it dynamic I just changed the title.

Comment: You likely dont need to slice anything,i'm pretty sure you can fix that with CSS,depending on the css framework you are using.Change the classes according to the number of skills displayed.

Comment: Don't see how you would do that? I cannot really see any other way of making the li-items span all three ul's? It is sort of the same problem as if you have paragraphs in columns and you want the text to continue uninterrupted across columns, but you don't know exactly where the column is going to break.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a columns array with start and end values for each column and use a nested repeater to loop through all the data and render properly.

```
<ul ng-repeat="column in columns" class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
  <li ng-repeat="skill in skills | slice:column.start:column.end">
    {{ skill }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Full plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/AMWLvB045UJmNamp8vdz?p=preview

Comment: Awesome solution! I had to tweak it a little bit to accomodate how I have nested my scope, but your example was very easy to follow. In addition I added logic to automatically determine number of columns. Here is the implementation I ended up using: https://gist.github.com/webconsult/e9afc4cd1c2d4eb4057d and you can check out the finished result at http://zkwsk.com when you go to the experience section and press "show all". Thanks!

Comment: @funkylaundry, glad it worked and thanks for posting a gist of what you ended up with after your tweaks.