# Dynamic multi-column checkboxes with AngularJS and Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need the ability to display a list of checkboxes in multiply columns and have not been able to figure out a why to make it work.  I am using AngularJS and Bootstrap.  This is what I have working right now but the checkboxes are in one column.

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-2">Tests Ordered:</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label ng-repeat="test in tests">
            <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.tests" checklist-value="test">&nbsp;{{test.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my controller this is the checkbox names -

```
$scope.tests = [{ name: "CardioIDgenetix 901", id: 0 }, { name: "NeuroIDgenetix 902", id: 1 }, { name: "Thrombophilia 403", id: 3 }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic concept to get you going:

```
<ul ng-repeat="column in columns" class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
  <li ng-repeat="skill in skills | slice:column.start:column.end">
    {{ skill }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For anyone wanting more info, this snippet is taken from this [full example here in another SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25655488/1554860)